# Use Levy's Continuity Theorem to show Poisson Approximation of the Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be random variables where $X_{n}$~$\operatorname{Bin}(n,p_{n})$ where $np_{n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}\lambda>0$

Show, using Levy's Continuity Theorem, that $X_{n} \xrightarrow{d} \operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)$ while $n \to \infty$

Only idea thus far:

$F_{X_{n}}(c)=P(X_{n} \leq c)=\sum_{k=0}^{c}\binom{n}{k}P(X_{n}=k)=\sum_{k=0}^{c}\binom{n}{k}(1-p_{n})^{n-k}(p_{n})^{k}$

I know that characteristic function is $\phi_{X_{n}}(t)=\mathbb E[e^{itX_{n}}]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}e^{itk}(1-p)^{n-k}p^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(1-p_{n})^{n-k}(e^{it}p_{n})^k$

How can I go on to use Levy's Continuity Theorem to show anything here?

Answer (score 2):

By the binomial theorem the last expression (with $p=p_n$) is $(e^{it}p_n+1-p)^n =\left(1-\frac{np_n(1-e^{it})}{n}\right)^n \to \exp(-\lambda(1-e^{it}))$ which is the characteristic function of the Poisson distribution.

Comment: I only have the following version of Levy's Continuity Theorem: Weak convergence between two finite measures $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu{2}$ $\iff$ pointwise convergence of the characteristic functions of $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu{2}$. But in this proof we are using convergence in distribution rather than weak convergence. Does weak convergence simply imply convergence in distribution?

Answer (score 1):

The theorem states that if the sequence of characteristic functions
$\phi_{X_n}(t)$ converges to a function which is the characteristic function of some other r.v., say $\phi_Y(t)$, then the sequence $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ converges in distribution to $Y$, that is
$$F_{X_n}(t)\to F_Y(t)$$
for every $t$.

Since $X_n\sim Bin(n,p_n)$, you can prove that
$$\phi_{X_n}(t)=(1-p_n+p_ne^it)^n,$$
so if you prove that for $n\to \infty$ this expression goes to
$$e^{\lambda (e^{it}-1)},$$
which is the characteristic function of any variable distributed as $\mathcal P(\lambda)$, then you can say that
$$X_n\to \mathcal P(\lambda),$$
as desired.